# How to use docker for sqs locally

Tags: docker, amazon-sqs

I am using AWS SQS in my project. I want to use this for local setup. For SQS, I have added [docker_local](https://github.com/vsouza/docker-SQS-local) on my project.

I have updated `Dockerfile` by adding this as suggested in the link.

```
FROM java:8

ADD https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/softwaremill-public/elasticmq-server-0.13.8.jar /
COPY custom.conf /
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java", "-Dconfig.file=custom.conf", "-jar", "/elasticmq-server-0.13.8.jar"]

EXPOSE 9324

CMD ["-help"]
```

When I execute command `docker ps` I get this on my screen:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
48e934fc6c43        mysql:5.7.16        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   24 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes       0.0.0.0:10612->3306/tcp   xyz_mysql_1
0af050bd3332        vsouza/sqs-local    "/usr/bin/java -Dcon…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:9324->9324/tcp    wizardly_yalow
```

I have added entry for sqs in my **docker-compose.yml** file too as:

```
sqs:
    image: s12v/elasticmq
    ports:
    - "9324:9324".
```

Now I am unable to understand how to use `SQS` in my console after going in shell of `SQS` using this command `sudo docker exec -it 0af050bd3332 sh`. When I try to list queue it is printing `sh: 2: list-queues: not found` error.

I have tried lots of things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I need to use docker to set up sqs in local env

Answer (score 9):

What your Dockerfile is doing is creating an ElasticMQ server. The latter is a ["message queue system"](https://github.com/softwaremill/elasticmq) which is compatible with SQS. So, you can use it the same exact way you use SQS, except you have to change the `endpoint` parameter when using the AWS CLI or SDK.

Let's do an interactive example here:

1. Run the following Docker command:

```
$ docker run -p 9324:9324 -p 9325:9325 softwaremill/elasticmq
```

2. Now, in another tab, execute the following AWS CLI command (notice the `--endpoint` parameter pointing to the locally running ElasticMQ server created above):

```
$ aws --region=us-west-2 --endpoint=http://localhost:9324 sqs list-queues
```

The result should be empty.

3. Now try to create a queue:

```
$ aws --region=us-west-2 --endpoint=http://localhost:9324 sqs create-queue --queue-name=test

{
    "QueueUrl": "http://localhost:9324/000000000000/test"
}
```

4. Now execute `list-queues` again and notice that you have a new queue:

```
$ aws --region=us-west-2 --endpoint=http://localhost:9324 sqs list-queues

{
    "QueueUrls": [
        "http://localhost:9324/000000000000/test"
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps!

Rafid

Comment: I feel this answer will be complete if you add how to push a message to the queue using aws-cli.
eg :  aws --region=us-east-1 --endpoint=http://localhost:9324 sqs send-message --queue-url http://localhost:9324/queue/test --message-body "{object:[{key:value, anotherkey:anothervalue}]}" --delay-seconds 5x`

Comment: It is asking for credentials.
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

Answer (score 1):

In our project we run [Localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) in docker. It has all AWS services available.

Very easy to use, [here](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) is an example docker compose file